# How to disable mouse right and middle click contexts on a google chrome page

Tags: windows, google-chrome, mouse, browser-addons

I play online HTML5 games and when I right click or middle click in one of those games I see the context. It's annoying, how may I disable it so chrome doesn't consume event but redirects it to game? Because I need to use right click as in game control key.